# Parse custom XML to JSON or Pandas DataFrame. (Python)

Tags: python, json, xml, pandas, xml-parsing

The following is my xml document.

```
<BizTalk xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Body>
<QUEUE>
  <FILTER FILTERNAME="CorrectAddress" VALUE="1" />
  <FILTER FILTERNAME="DaysSinceLastTracking" VALUE="0" />
  <FILTER FILTERNAME="DaysSinceShipped" VALUE="3" />
  <FILTER FILTERNAME="DaysUntilDelivered" VALUE="735101" />
  <FILTER FILTERNAME="DeliveryStatus" VALUE="IN_TRANSIT" />
  <FILTER FILTERNAME="Division" VALUE="71" />
  <FILTER FILTERNAME="EmptyBox" VALUE="0" />
  <FILTER FILTERNAME="FedVendInstructions" VALUE="" />
  <FILTER FILTERNAME="ItemDescription" VALUE="bla bla bla" />
  <FILTER FILTERNAME="ItemIssue" VALUE="Damaged" />
  <FILTER FILTERNAME="ItemValue" VALUE="50" />
  <FILTER FILTERNAME="PiecedSet" VALUE="0" />
  <FILTER FILTERNAME="HasProofOfDelivery" VALUE="0" />
  <FILTER FILTERNAME="RecievedPOD" VALUE="0" />
  <FILTER FILTERNAME="RequestedAction" VALUE="Reship" />
  <FILTER FILTERNAME="HasReturntracking" VALUE="0" />
  <FILTER FILTERNAME="IsStandardFillLocation" VALUE="1" />
  <FILTER FILTERNAME="Tampered" VALUE="0" />
  <FILTER FILTERNAME="HasTracking" VALUE="1" />
  <FILTER FILTERNAME="ShortName" VALUE="BDD" />
  <FILTER FILTERNAME="IsBOPS" VALUE="0" />
  <FILTER FILTERNAME="WrongItemType" VALUE="" />
</QUEUE>
<RESPONSEDATA>
  <ITEMS>
    <DATA CanReOrder="1" UPC="xxxxxxx" Quantity="1" LineNumber="1" Description="bla bla bla" />
  </ITEMS>
  <DATA ITEM="Reservation" VALUE="????????" />
  <DATA ITEM="ShipmentNumber" VALUE="1" />
  <DATA ITEM="ContactedBy" VALUE="Shipping Customer" />
  <DATA ITEM="PackageRecieved" VALUE="1" />
  <DATA ITEM="CheckedEverywhere" VALUE="0" />
</RESPONSEDATA>
```

How do I convert this custom XML to Pandas DataFrame?

I tried some pre-defined coversions using xmljson which throws up error "str object doesn't have attribute tag"

I tried using ELementTree and passing the list of element tree object to Pandas and it throws up empty Dataframe:

```
etree = ET.fromstring(xml_data)
df = pd.DataFrame(list(etree))
print(df)
```

I'm currently planning to write custom Parser which takes in **FilterName** as Column name, and Value as its field, but that is hard coding. I want to avoid this thing in future, as if more fields are added, I'll have to manually add them which is hassle.

Is there some way where I can iterate through each line (That can be done using Loop with Open). And dynamically add columns to Pandas DataFrame?

Or is there some efficient way?

Note: I checked the validity of XML on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp) and It says not errors found, so I believe the XML is valid though.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Cool, I found a solution to this. I did the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

etree = ET.fromstring(xml_data)
# root = etree.getroot()
for node in etree.findall('.//FILTER'):
    parent = node.attrib.get('FILTERNAME')
    child = node.attrib.get('VALUE')

    col_name = parent
    val = child

    df[col_name] = [val]
```

print(df)

Just wanted to post, so that anyone faces similar issue, it can be of help. Thanks